# Sending Group SMS iOS Swift - How to go beyond carrier's restriction of 9 - 20 messages per send attempt

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am designing an iOS app that receives multiple contact numbers from a server and sends messages to those numbers. I have made this service with an external API called Twilio, but Twilio costs(quite a lot actually if all my users are to send bulk messages). I want to make this App free for use and to make the user pay for the number of text messages they send, which will be charged by their carrier.

I found an app called 'Group SMS 4!' by Cedars and this app does exactly what I wanted. I'm sharing you the link for the app on the appstore

[Group SMS 4!](https://apps.apple.com/kr/app/group-sms-4/id398189559)

I've used the app, and I know it doens't use an external SMS gateway but MFMessageComposeViewController. But I though sending programmatically through iPhone restricted the number of texts sent to be less than 9 ~ 20 (depending on the carrier).

So my conjecture on how this problem was solved was,

- Divide the contacts in a group of 5~9 somehow and send them separately, and sequentially when send button is pressed

Was my guess correct? If not, What would be a way to achieve this? I just need the user to be able to send up to 100 people automatically and without hassle. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask the developer support@cedars.kr - sometimes they can be surprisingly helpful and friendly.  Another approach is to write a sample app that does as you suggest and see if it works.  I think if pay-for APIs are too heavily used, it can cause App Store rejection.